# Read a file into memory and re-use in script

Tags: linux, performance, memory

I have a large (1 GB) file that I want to process with a script. I'm still experimenting with how I want to process this file. So my script keeps changing as I try different things. The problem is, it takes a long time to read the file into memory. Is there a way to read the file into memory once and just keep accessing that memory each time I run my script? That would make my script a lot faster. I switched to using a REPL for now, but curious if this can be done with a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in [Linux using ramfs and tmpfs](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/overview-of-ramfs-and-tmpfs-on-linux/)

In Windows, you can use a tool like [Imdisk](http://lifehacker.com/imdisk-creates-dynamically-resizing-ram-disks-1509758781)

The idea is you create a disk backed by your RAM.
After creating the disk, copy the file to it - you are essentially writing the file to RAM.

Your script can then read the file from the ramfs/tmpfs/ramdisk.
This should be faster since there will be no disk spinning around,
although this will require at least 1GB of your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: No, there is no such way doing this. :/

Comment: At least as for as i know and i am pretty sure about it.